# Element width based on how many siblings are present

Tags: css, css-float, width

Say I have a ul of 500px. Say that the child li's are float left. Is there a way to write the css so the li's never go to a second line but fill up the 500px width of the ul based on how many li's are present?

For example.

```
<ul>
   <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

the li would take up the entire 500px

```
<ul>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

the 2 li would split the width. essentially each 250px each

```
<ul>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

would split it 3 ways etc...

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ul {
    width: 500px;
    display: table;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WhbuQ/

Comment: Thank you for this. Always forget about the table/table-cell display types. This works great for everything except ie7. Any solution that includes ie7?

Comment: @KyleWilliams - Unfortunately, nope. I don't know if it's possible to achieve this sort of layout in IE7 without manually adding classes and percentages.

Answer (score 0):

When [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) becomes finalized/better implemented, it would provide a nice option.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcbWa/) using an old-style syntax supported by current Gecko/Webkit.